# Use replace() selectively?

Tags: javascript

I have hierarhical dropdown which has 3+ steps. Im using very convenient WordPress function which uses `&nbsp;` to fake `<optgroup>` / hierarchy. Don't tell me to use `<optgroup>` like everybody else, it **doesn't work** with more than 2 steps in hierarchy.

Strings in `HTML` looks something like this:

```
Colors&nbsp;&nbsp;(21)
&nbsp;&nbsp;Red&nbsp;&nbsp;(7)
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dark&nbsp;&nbsp;(3)
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Light&nbsp;&nbsp;(4)
&nbsp;&nbsp;Blue&nbsp;&nbsp;(13)
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dark&nbsp;&nbsp;(5)
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Light&nbsp;&nbsp;(8)
&nbsp;&nbsp;Yellow&nbsp;&nbsp;(1)
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Light&nbsp;&nbsp;(1)
```

Which outputs something like this in dropdown:

```
Colors (21)
  Red (7)
    Dark (3)
    Light (4)
  Blue (13)
    Dark (5)
    Light (8)
  Yellow (1)
    Light (1)
```

---

I need to remove the white space **before** the word when the item is selected.

Im currently using `myString.html.replace( /&nbsp;/g,'' );` but it also removes white space between the word and *(count)*.

**How to remove the white space only before the word and not between the word and *(count)*?**

Comment: *"I need to remove the white space before the word when the item is selected"* - Why? Won't that be confusing for the user if they go to change the selection? (And don't forget to put the spaces back again if they do change the selection.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Im not removing white space from within dropdown itself, only from label that shows *active* / *selected* option. There's no need to change anything back because it doesn't change dropdown itself and hierarchy stays the same. Im not sure what you mean by confusing because it doesn't change anything important and it looks awful among different types of other inputs that doesn't have white space before the values.

Comment: Your question only mentioned the drop down, not any label displaying the same value, so I thought you wanted to remove spaces from within the actual option element that is selected. *That* could be confusing for users. Now that you've explained that you're not doing that, well, no problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the starts with notation, which will select only `&nbsp;` at the beginning of the string

```
myString.html.replace( /^(&nbsp;)+/,'');
```

Comment: `^`  matches the beginning of the string, not of the line - unless you use the [multiline flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/multiline)

Comment: Remember that for more complex replace logic, you can pass in a function rather than a string as a replacement. This can be a really powerful way of isolating complex logic and making your code more readable. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) for details.